# ScrollView on material-bottom-tabs not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

**Current Behavior**

I'm creating my tabs like this (note: Home is a StackNavigator screen):

[image: carbon (3)]

ProfileTab is rendered this way (items is an array of inputs):

```
return <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: Colors.primaryShade3,
                                               paddingTop: Sizes.paddingTop}}>
              <View style={{flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", marginBottom: 50}}>
                  <Image source={{uri: RNStorage.userProfile.user.photo}} 
                         style={{marginRight: 20, resizeMode: "contain", width: 70, height: 70, borderRadius: 50}}/>
                  <Text style={{color: Colors.white, fontSize: Sizes.h2}}>
                    Bem vindo, {RNStorage.userProfile.user.givenName}
                  </Text>
              </View>                            
              {items}
   </ScrollView>
```

All inputs follow this structure:

[image: carbon (4)]

Currently having this behavior (Not scrolling):

[image: ezgif com-video-to-gif (1)]

**Expected Behavior**

Scroll should work normally. I also tested using the ScrollView of the react-native-gesture-handler but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unrelated to material-bottom-tabs.

You need to remove `flex: 1` from `contentContainerStyle`. Otherwise your view will fill available scrollable area and won't be scrollable.